# SQL Search two columns and replace third

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to search a table for matches in 2 columns and replace the content in a 3rd column. So something like:

```
Search table 'postmeta' for
post_id = 1234
**AND** meta_key = _product_id
REPLACE meta_value = 5678`
```

Table structure is

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
```

Comment: What your database? Syntax might differ.

Answer (score 2):

Use [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

`UPDATE postmeta SET meta_value = 5678 WHERE post_id = 1234 AND meta_key = '_product_id'`

> For the single-table syntax, the **UPDATE** statement updates columns of
>   existing rows in the named table with new values. The **SET** clause
>   indicates which columns to modify and the values they should be given.
>   Each value can be given as an expression, or the keyword **DEFAULT** to
>   set a column explicitly to its default value. The **WHERE** clause, if
>   given, specifies the conditions that identify which rows to update.
>   With no **WHERE** clause, all rows are updated. If the **ORDER BY** clause is
>   specified, the rows are updated in the order that is specified. The
>   **LIMIT** clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated.